# Show uncaught exception in console when using winston (node.js)

Tags: node.js, winston

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
 var winston = require('winston');
 winston.add(winston.transports.File, { filename: 'test.log', handleExceptions: true, humanReadableUnhandledException: true });
 throw "test";
```

In test.log, winston does log the error properly.

But I'd also like it to show the error in the console as well like it normally does.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Console transport to winston, along with existing File transport:

```
 winston.add(winston.transports.Console, options)
```

https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md#console-transport